# What are the Default and extra fields used for in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Whenever we create a table in MySQL using the command line client why does it add the default and extra field in the table?

[image: click here to see the fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not fields in the table. Every column must have a default value and if you don't give one it will be NULL.

The extra shows information like auto_increment etc that is important about the column.

All this is shown because of the command line tool.